# mailmerge with visto how to get each record of MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-word, vsto

I' have a Project that needs to do a mailmerge, I'm performing this with VSTO. I need to check if all records on the `MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields` are ok. i'm doing that with this code.

```
    public void verificarPersonas(Word.Document Doc)
    {
        ThisAddIn ThisAddIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
        List<Personas> miListaPersonas = new List<Personas>();
        decimal nRecords = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount;
        if (nRecords == 0)
        {
            cambiarEstado("Empty db  or documento does'n prepared for mail merge", false);
        }
        else
        {
            string fieldIdentificacion = persParm("Identificacion");
            string fieldNombre = persParm("Nombres");
            string fieldApellido = persParm("Apellidos");
            string fieldEmail = persParm("Email");
            string fieldDireccion = persParm("Direccion");
            string fieldTelefono = persParm("Telefono");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldIdentificacion) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldNombre))
            {
                cambiarEstado("", false);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= nRecords; i++)
                {
                    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i;
                    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = i;

                    //   Here Allways get the first record
                    dynamic fields = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields;
                    //    ________________________________
                    Personas personaActual = new Personas();
                    personaActual.IdPersona = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        personaActual.Identificacion = fields(fieldIdentificacion).value;
                        personaActual.Nombres = fields(fieldNombre).value;
                        personaActual.Apellidos = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldApellido) ? "" : fields(fieldApellido).value);
                        personaActual.Email = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldEmail) ? "" : fields(fieldEmail).value);
                        personaActual.Direccion = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldDireccion) ? "" : fields(fieldDireccion).value);
                        personaActual.Telefono = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTelefono) ? "" : fields(fieldTelefono).value);

                        miListaPersonas.Add(personaActual);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        cambiarEstado(""+e.Message, false);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                string listaPersonasJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(miListaPersonas);
                string respuesta = wt.getWebData("Personas", "verificarPersonasVSTO", new { personas = listaPersonasJson });

            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that `dynamic fields = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields;` allways get the first record.

How can I do to get `datafields` for the active record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research and some tries. get that the fields collection of datasource dont move the pointer when you set FirstRecord and Lastrecord, it must be moved using activerecords, using  WdMailMergeActiveRecord enumeration, sonething like this:

```
int nRecords = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount;

for (int i = 1; i <= nRecords; i++)
{
    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i; //It doesn't work 
    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = i; // it doesn't work
    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = (i == 1 ?   
    Word.WdMailMergeActiveRecord.wdFirstDataSourceRecord :Word.WdMailMergeActiveRecord.wdNextDataSourceRecord);
    Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = (i == nRecords ? Word.WdMailMergeActiveRecord.wdLastDataSourceRecord : Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord);
    dynamic fields = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields;
}
```